To schedule data refreshes in Power BI for data coming from SQL Server standard , what type of additional set up are required?
We had taken data from SAP into SQL Server using connectors. Since we are using SQL Server standard edition, I am using a SQL Server stored procedure as data source in Power BI, so is there any additional set up or code required to schedule refresh in Power BI service, because I am using the SAP data into the stored procedure? Except Gateway.

Didn't you already ask this question and someone answered it?

Re-asking a question without addressing the close reason will just get closed again.

@siggemannen i did'nt got proper answer

@DaleK I did not got proper answer could please answer if you know?
